# jQuery .on() not bound when script inserted into the DOM

Tags: javascript, events, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a remote javascript file containing a custom jQuery event handler. When this is inserted into the DOM as a `<script src='...'></script>` element, the custom event handler is not registered.

However, if I add the exact same script as straight JS (`<script>...</script>`), the event handler is registered, and everything executes as expected.

Why isn't the event handler being bound in jQuery when the script is inserted as a remote file?

### Example

The remote file, containing the custom event handler:

```js
console.log('Before custom event handler');
$('button').on('customEvent', function(){
    console.log('customEvent Caught');
});
```

https://gist.github.com/2767385

The (*non-working*) javascript which inserts the script into the DOM:

```js
var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
    scriptNode.src = 'https://gist.github.com/raw/2767385/b9ddea612ff60b334bd2430e59903174e527a3b5/gistfile1.js';
document.body.appendChild(scriptNode);
```

The (*working alternative*) javascript which inserts the script as inline into the DOM:

```js
var scriptText = "console.log('Before custom event handler'); $('button').on('customEvent', function(){ console.log('customEvent Caught'); });",
    scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
document.body.appendChild(scriptNode);
```

Triggering the event:

```js
$('button').triggerHandler('customEvent');
```

The JS is correctly read, and the handler is correctly executed.

#### JSFiddles

*Remote file* - non-working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3CfFM/3/
*Using Text* - working alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/3CfFM/2/

### What's happening?

Why isn't the event handler being bound in jQuery when the script is inserted as a remote file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken. The event handler *is* being bound when used with a remote script; it simply takes a little longer. The browser needs to make an HTTP request before it binds the handler. This means that the original event you trigger with `triggerHandler('customEvent')` is not captured, since its bubbling and capturing has already completed.

If you wait a second, then click the button again, you will see that the event handler has indeed been bound. You can also see this by delaying your `triggerHandler` call until the script has loaded:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
    scriptNode.src = 'https://gist.github.com/raw/2767385/897cffca74411dbb542c0713bacb5a4048d6708b/gistfile1.js';
    scriptNode.onload = function() {
        $('button').triggerHandler('customEvent');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(scriptNode);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3CfFM/4/

Comment: A-Ha! On top of waiting for the script to download, an important point of difference between my jsfiddle and yours: I was calling `$(this).triggerHandler(...)`, while you are (more correctly) calling `$('button').triggerHandler(...)`!

Comment: No, there's no difference. In your script, `this` is the button. In mine, because I have an additional event handler (the `onload` method) `this` would be the `scriptNode` element.